# Determine ranges overlap, including smaller than and greater than ranges

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, math, range

I have a list of integer ranges.
When I create a new range (x-y), how would one check the list (using `LINQ` or otherwise) and decide whether the newly created range satisfies conditions to be inserted into the list:

- Newly created item cannot be inserted if it overlaps any existing item
- Newly created item can be inserted if it has smaller x and smaller y than any of the items
- Newly created item can be inserted if it has greater x and greater t than any of the items

  ```
         <----O---->
    <--------->
             ^ NOT OK

         <----O---->
              <--------->
             ^ NOT OK

         <----O---->
             <-->
             ^ OK

         <----O---->
       <-------------->
             ^ OK
         <----O---->
   <--->
             ^ OK
         <----O---->
                      <--->
             ^ OK
  ```

I got it working if the only rule was for items to never overlap (but can be the same limit)

```
if (List.Any(listItem => listItem.X <= newItem.Y && listItem.Y >= newItem.X)) return false;
```

The problem raises when I need to check for other two conditions.
Is this even possible? Thanks!

Edit:
The solution was similar to `Apoorva Jhanwer`'s answer, the method `TrueForAll` helped me.

```
if (newList.TrueForAll(listItem => 
    newItem.X < listItem.X && newItem.Y > listItem.Y 
    || newItem.X > listItem.X && newItem.Y < listItem.Y 
    || newItem.X < listItem.X && newItem.Y < listItem.X 
    || newItem.X > listItem.Y && newItem.Y > listItem.Y )) return true;
```

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd conditions are either implicit in the first one or explicitly allow overlap for edge-cases (therefore breaking the first condition). Which one is it?

Comment: The diagram and the conditions are somewhat unrelated. Your "OK" cases obviously overlap but don't satisfy any of the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   if (list.TrueForAll(listItem => (newItem.X < listItem.X && newItem.Y > listItem.Y )||(newItem.X > listItem.X && newItem.Y < listItem.Y)))return true;
```

Just check for conditions that are true

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the solution was somewhat different but `List.TrueForAll` helped me!